# Adding a Collection to a list in Android

Tags: android, list, collections

I have a collection that Id like to add to a list in my app. From the docs it seems like my code should work but it is not. Can anyone see the problem?

```
       final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    final Collection<String> collection = new Collection<String>() { //Collection initializer
    };

    collection.add("X");
    collection.add("Z");


    list.add("Jim");
    list.add("Pim");



    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list.addAll(collection);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This can't be the code. Also, define "doesn't work".

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry Dave, CaseyB answered my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an implementation of `Collection` that doesn't actually have anything in it.  You should really be using one of the existing `Collection` subclasses instead of making your own.

Comment: Ooooh I totally overlooked that fact. Everything is working now. Thanks!